# Using array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The jsp page is not recognizing my `array aa[]` in the line `document.dd.aa[i].value`....
to be specific dd is my form name....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function chk()
{
    var errmsg = new String("");
    var aa = new Array("t1","t2");
    for(var i=0;i<=1;i++)
        {
           var ddd = document.dd.aa[i].value;
           if(ddd=="")
               {
                  errmsg += "Empty field:" +"\n";
               }
        }
        alert(errmsg);
}
</script>
```

Thx in advance :DD...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var aa = new Array("t1","t2");
```

Above is not part of the form. So `var ddd = document.dd.aa[i].value;` is wrong.

You can directly access aa array.
So do like this.

```
var ddd = aa[i];
```

Answer (score 4):

To access the array, it's simply:

```
var ddd = aa[i];
```

Also, it's better to create the array using literals:

```
var aa = ['t1','t2'];
```

If `dd` is a form, then `document.dd` returns the DOM form element named `dd`. To access the elements, you need to traverse the element using DOM traversal methods, like `getElementById`, `getElementsByTagName` and so on.

Comment: Just to add a little bit to the answer: It's simply because javascript variables are not bound to the DOM so you don't need to navigate to access them. You use the DOM to get data from page's elements, like for example, user input.

Comment: @RobertoLinares thanks for the add. I missed the part that `dd` was a form.